# Framer X - how to jump to next page automatically

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, prototype, framerjs

I recently dove into Framer X to make the prototype, and in some page I want to play the gif to demonstrate the process of loading and after that it will jump to next page automatically may be after 3s, although I haven't find any resources in the internet for the this effect but I still want to finish the prototype by using Framer X.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple javascript TimeOut

```
setTimeout(function() { callThisFuncion()}, 3000)
```

The above line calls the function `callThisFuncion()` after `3000` ms (or 3 seconds)